# calculating current value based on previous value

Tags: python, loops

i would like to perform a calculation using python, where the current value (i) of the equation is based on the previous value of the equation (i-1), which is really easy to do in a spreadsheet but i would rather learn to code it

i have noticed that there is loads of information on finding the previous value from a list, but i don't have a list i need to create it! my equation is shown below.

```
h=(2*b)-h[i-1]
```

can anyone give me tell me a method to do this ?

i tried this sort of thing, but that will not work as when i try to do the equation i'm calling a value i haven't created yet, if i set h=0 then i get an error that i am out of index range

```
i = 1
for i in range(1, len(b)):
    h=[]
    h=(2*b)-h[i-1]
    x+=1
```

Comment: By `h1 = n - h0` and `h2 = n - h1` substitute `n - h0` for `h1` in the second one and you have `h2 = h0`.  Your sequence is a flip-flop alternating the values `h0` and `h1`. You can compute the value of the sequence for arbitrarily large `n` by calling this function `def h(n, ho, b): return 2*b-h0 if n%2 else h0` or maybe inlining the `.. if ... else ...` expression

Comment: Is ```b``` an ```int```?  Would `h` be something like - ```[0, f(0), f(f(0)), f(f(f(0)), ...)```?

Comment: @wwii `b` can be an integer, a real, a complex ... `h2 = n - (n-h0) = h0`

Comment: @gboffi I was thinking about a general solution.

Comment: @wwii I got your comment in my mailbox, and I had just posted my comment about the _particular case of recursion_ of the OP, so I misunderstood your Q

Answer (score 0):

```
h = []
for i in range(len(b)):
     if i>0:
          h.append(2*b - h[i-1])
     else:
         # handle i=0 case here
```

Comment: And for a big list, you will check value on every iteration? I am not talking about the ugly __for i in range(len(b))__ (and without semicolon)

Comment: @volcano it is not clear from the OPs question or code if he wanted to retain all the values (which I assume since he's comparing it to excel) so I've written an answer closest to the code he provided. If its something like a markov chain then I would use a different method ofcourse. And btw, range is same as xrange in python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = [b[0]]
for val in b[1:]:
    h.append(2 * val - h[-1]) # As you add to h, you keep up with its tail
```

for large **b** list (brr, one-letter identifier), to avoid creating large slice

```
from itertools import islice # For big list it will keep code less wasteful
for val in islice(b, 1, None):
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @pad, you simply need to handle the base case of receiving the first sample.

However, your equation makes no use of *i* other than to retrieve the previous result. It's looking more like a running filter than something which needs to maintain a list of past values (with an array which might never stop growing).

If that is the case, and you only ever want the most recent value,then you might want to go with a generator instead.

```
def gen():   
    def eqn(b):
        eqn.h = 2*b - eqn.h
        return eqn.h

    eqn.h = 0
    return eqn
```

And then use thus

```
>>> f = gen()
>>> f(2)
4
>>> f(3)
2
>>> f(2)
0
>>>
```

The same effect could be acheived with a true generator using yield and send.

Answer (score 0):

First of, do you need all the intermediate values? That is, do you want a list `h` from `0` to `i`? Or do you just want `h[i]`?

If you just need the i-th value you could us recursion:

```
def get_h(i):
  if i>0:
    return (2*b) - get_h(i-1)
  else:
    return h_0
```

But be aware that this will not work for large i, as it will exceed the maximum recursion depth. (Thanks for pointing this out kdopen) In that case a simple for-loop or a generator is better.

Even better is to use a (mathematically) closed form of the equation (for your example that is possible, it might not be in other cases):

```
def get_h(i):
  if i%2 == 0:
    return h_0
  else:
    return (2*b)-h_0
```

In both cases `h_0` is the initial value that you start out with.

Comment: For your first example, what happens on get_h(1000000)? In the second, where is h_0 coming from?

Comment: @kdopen: On your first point: The same as with any other large i: A long and expensive recursion chain is going to be evaluated. But assuming one does only want one single h value for a specific i and has an equation without a closed form all that computations have to be done to get a result in any algorithm. I one wants all values up to a certain i, your approach with a generator is certainly more efficient. As for the h_0: Any formula that depends on a previous evaluation needs an initial value. I thought h_0 would be a self-explanatory name. I will edit my post to make I more understandable

Comment: There are two problems with a recursive solution in this case. First, I don't think it's a recursive equation (though it looks like it): 'i-1' is just symbolic of 'the previous answer'. Secondly, Python has a fixed recursion limit (1000 by default), so for get_h(1001) you will get an exception. If you want to recursively calculate this, without storing the intermediates, you need to know what value of 'b' was used at each iteration.

Comment: You are right about the recursion depth of cause, thanks for pointing that out. As to the other: I think that is a matter of interpretation of the question. In my understanding b is a constant. The question author should clarify what is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You are successively applying a function (equation) to the result of a previous application of that function - **the process needs a seed to start it**.  Your result looks like this `[seed, f(seed), f(f(seed)), f(f(f(seed)), ...]`.  This concept is `function composition`.  You can create a generalized function that will do this for any sequence of functions, in Python functions are first class objects and can be passed around just like any other object.  If you need to preserve the intermediate results use a generator.

```
def composition(functions, x):
    """ yields f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x)) ....

    for each f in functions
    functions is an iterable of callables taking one argument
    """
    for f in functions:
        x = f(x)
        yield x
```

Your specs require a seed and a constant,

```
seed = 0
b = 10
```

The equation/function,

```
def f(x, b = b):
    return 2*b - x
```

`f` is applied `b` times.

```
functions = [f]*b
```

Usage

```
print list(composition(functions, seed))
```

If the intermediate results are not needed `composition` can be redefined as

```
def composition(functions, x):
    """ Returns f(x), g(f(x)), h(g(f(x)) ....

    for each function in functions
    functions is an iterable of callables taking one argument
    """
    for f in functions:
        x = f(x)
    return x

print composition(functions, seed)
```

Or more generally, with no limitations on call signature:

```
def compose(funcs):
    '''Return a callable composed of successive application of functions

    funcs is an iterable producing callables
    for [f, g, h] returns f(g(h(*args, **kwargs)))
    '''
    def outer(f, g):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(g(*args, **kwargs))
        return inner
    return reduce(outer, funcs)

def plus2(x):
    return x + 2
def times2(x):
    return x * 2
def mod16(x):
    return x % 16

funcs = (mod16, plus2, times2)
eq = compose(funcs)   # mod16(plus2(times2(x)))
print eq(15)
```

While the process definition appears to be recursive, I resisted the temptation so I could stay out of `maximum recursion depth` hades.

I got curious, searched SO for `function composition` and, of course, there are numerous relavent Q&A's.